# SQL Server 2008 Login Problem

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to install yet another forum on my local machine, and while I'm configuring the database connection I got this message

> Failed to connect:
>
> Login failed for user 'NT
>   AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.

I have served Google and I found that I have to add network service Login to my SQL server and then add this user to my database

I don't know if this is true or false but anyway I don't know hot to add the network service to my SQL server

please help as soon as you can

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the Identity of the Appplication Pool in IIS

Local database, same box as IIS:

```
CREATE LOGIN [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE] FROM WINDOWS;
```

Local or remote database in Active Directory domain

```
CREATE LOGIN [myDomain\ServerName$] FROM WINDOWS;
```

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend changing the application pool identity to a dedicated account for the site if using Windows authentication, but yes, this should work.

Comment: @db2: agree: this is I do.

Answer (score 4):

Goto SQL Server Management Studio => `Security`. Right click on `Logins` => `New Login`.
In `Login name` type `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`. Click ok.

Now click on your yaf database => `Security`. Right click on `users` => `New User...`
Fill in the `username` your desired name. in `Login name` type `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`. Choose `db_owner` in `Schemas` and `Database Role Membership` click ok.

You should be able to login to your databse with your desired username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with gbn and Kamyar. You can preview the example/tutorial on [here](http://windows2008hosting.asphostportal.com/post/SQL-2008-Hosting-ASPHostPortal-Login-failed-for-user-NT-AUTHORITY5cIUSR.aspx).